# Error constantly occurring when reviewing proposed change

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, error-message

https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/documentation/proposed/changes/26847

Whenever I go to review the above proposed change in documentation, it always comes up with the message

> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site.

I have tried to review this for several days but have not seen it so far. Is this a bug?

Comment: I've seen this on another proposed change, too. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/44522) by MSalters in the C++ tag. Hasn't worked for a couple of days now.

Comment: Yup, definitely repros... I'm looking. Edit: I've added some extra logging that will help us diagnose this (I have a hunch, but I want to confirm it); should be able to deploy that in the next few hours; Edit 2: what is happening here is that the *old* edit did an in-place edit of an example that was moved **while the first draft was in the review queue**; I'm seeking guidance on the intended behavior here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the affected proposals edit examples that have **in the interim** been moved and edited separately. The affected proposal should have been automatically marked/revoked as un-mergeable, but this did not happen (and I will continue to investigate why).

Now, the damaged draft will at least *load*, but reflects the fact that it is in a state where it can't be merged (and cannot be approved).