# What does it mean for a draft to be in invalid state

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, documentation

For example this one:

[Using TypeScript with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/40247)

```
resurrected 1 examples (invalid)  
Allow loader to handle .ts and .tsx files.  
STATUS:   Awaiting approval
This draft cannot be approved as it is in an invalid state.
```

The only available action now for this change is 'Reject' which does not seem right because it does not even show what is in that resurrected example

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yup; so it turns out that we had a bug in the code that runs when *one* proposal is approved that is meant to check for *competing* pending approvals, and checks for conflicts. If there is an fundamental conflict, the *other* proposals are meant to be automatically rejected as being in a conflicted state. The code was *close*, but it accidentally tripped over one scenario, where proposal A is *moving* an example, and proposal B is *editing* an example in the context of a draft. It should have marked B as unmergeable, but it didn't. In this scenario, [the change from your question](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/40247) is B; it is an edit from 2016-07-23 11:30:52.070  (with the proposal created 2016-07-23 11:34:43.833) to topic 2024, editing example 6621 ("Install and configure webpack + loaders"). However, example 6621 **isn't there any more**; it is [now on topic 2860](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/typescript/2860/integrating-with-build-tools/6621/install-and-configure-webpack-loaders#t=201608171352119121608). It was [moved](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/typescript/revisions/2860?exampleId=6621) on July 24th.

Basically, this situation should have been resolved automatically, but: it wasn't. The bug that allowed this has been fixed, but we have *not* automatically revoked those proposals; but just the same as if they had been *automatically* revoked, it will need manual fixing. But it felt inherently wrong to have a GET request that revoked it on discovery.

The reason it "does not even show what is in that resurrected example" is because this is truly a broken scenario; I *could* have changed the UI to make it fetch all the additional data, but it felt redundant since it isn't meant to happen, and should now go away once the affected proposals have worked their way through. But on the plus side, until yesterday [it wouldn't have loaded at all](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332410/error-constantly-occurring-when-reviewing-proposed-change/332498#332498).